# Call shared function from asp page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an object on a page which needs to databind itself and the code I have written works. However, I would like to store the code in a SharedFunctions.cs file so I can use it on multiple pages. (This will open up the door for further shared functions)

ASP Page looks like this:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="hlSchedule" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Schedule.aspx" 
       Visible='<%#Session["bnManager"]%>' 
       OnInit="SharedFunctions.DatabindThis">Schedule</asp:HyperLink>
```

SharedFunctions.cs file looks like this:

```
namespace ProjectHub
{
    public class SharedFunctions
    {
        public static void DatabindThis(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dynamic o = sender;
            o.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

The error I have shows:

> Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'main_master' does not contain a
>   definition for 'SharedFunctions' and no extension method
>   'SharedFunctions' accepting a first argument of type 'main_master'
>   could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

What am I doing wrong and what is the best way to store and call shared code across multiple pages?

Thanks

Comment: I cannot simply call the method either ie: 'main_master' does not contain a definition for 'DatabindThis'

Comment: Try putting `<%@ Import Namespace="ProjectHub.SharedFunctions" %>` at the top of your aspx page.

Comment: I get an error when I try this: A 'using namespace' directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'SharedFunctions' is a type not a namespace. Consider a 'using static' directive instead

Comment: ok sorry yes sorry that's the result of me just dashing off a comment without looking properly. It should clearly just reference the namespace, not a specific class. My mistake. Although perhaps you could have worked that out from the error message and the directive name (the clue being "Import **Namespace**)? Try `<%@ Import Namespace="ProjectHub" %>`

Comment: Actually I tried <%@ Import Namespace="ProjectHub.SharedFunctions" %> before I saw your message, and declaring the namespace the same within the class file, this yeilds the same result as specifying the ProjectHub as the namespace. However, whilst there is no error relating to the import statement, asp still can't see the Public Static Void DatabindThis.. (CS1061: 'main_master' does not contain a definition for 'DatabindThis') I also tried renaming it to public void. I'm a little lost why it's slightly complicated to share code between pages.. I must be close, any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Looking more closely at the way you're trying to use this, I think actually you should make the target of OnInit a standard event handler method within your page's code-behind, and that event handler method would call DatabindThis, passing along the sender and eventargs objects. TBH though unless you've got something more complex in mind for future additions to your shared functions, for the sake of saving two lines of code in a few places (`dynamic o = sender;
            o.DataBind();`) you're creating a lot more complexity and hassle instead.

Comment: P.S. I think the Import Namespace command only works if you're then using inline C# code within your ASPX page, e.g. within `<% %>` brackets. Not sure it works for event handlers. I think event handlers need to be defined within the ASPX or its master page, as far as I know, especially if you're using AutoEventWireUp

Comment: I actually come from a php background, this is my first asp project, so some of the methods I used to work with I am trying to port across. Yes for now, I will may as well copy the two lines of code in all asp pages I need to use the databind, most pages will use this same code. Though the understanding would have been used for more complicated shared functions at a later date. Thanks for taking the time to reach out to me. It was really appreciated.

Comment: Ah yes ASP.NET Forms is wildly different to anything PHP can offer. It's basically an attempt to port the event model from Windows Forms and shoehorn it into a web environment, where it sits a bit awkwardly IMHO. ASP.NET MVC is a _bit_ more like a PHP style of things (and the natural order of the Web in general) and is certainly more like PHP MVC frameworks such as Laravel etc. TBH having used both for many years (and lots of PHP too!) I think MVC is the better of the two ASP.NET idioms and has more of a future, but it's horses for courses I guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156564/discussion-between-tommylux-and-adyson).